# How to refactor method with multiple boolean variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, code-cleanup

I have a method in ruby which sets a few instance variables, conditionally and I'm wondering how I could refactor it to clean it up and make it less verbose. My first though was to break the different conditions up into multiple smaller helper methods, but I'm not sure if that is the right way to go about it. Any advise would be helpful.

```
def admin_view
    if resource.present?
      if resource.ed_level == 'group'
        if current_user && (current_user.admin || resource.admins_byemail.include?(current_user.email))
          @admin_full = true
          @admin_edit = true
          @admin_view = true
        else
          @admin_full = false
          @admin_edit = false
          @admin_view = false
        end
      else
        if current_user && (current_user.admin || resource.admin_email_list('view').include?(current_user.email.downcase))
          if current_user.admin || (resource.admin_email_list('full').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group')
            @admin_full = true
            @admin_edit = true
            @admin_view = true
          elsif resource.admin_email_list('edit').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group'
            @admin_full = false
            @admin_edit = true
            @admin_view = true
          elsif resource.admin_email_list('view').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group'
            @admin_full = false
            @admin_edit = false
            @admin_view = true
          end
        else
          @admin_full = false
          @admin_edit = false
          @admin_view = false
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_to school_missing_path
    end
  end
```

Based on the answer below, I've updated my code as follows.

```
 def admin_view
    if resource.present?
      if resource.ed_level == 'group'
        if current_user && (current_user.admin || resource.admins_byemail.include?(current_user.email))
          set_admin_permissions(full: true, edit: true, view: true)
        else
          set_admin_permissions(full: false, edit: false, view: false)
        end
      else
        if current_user && (current_user.admin || resource.admin_email_list('view').include?(current_user.email.downcase))
          if current_user.admin || (resource.admin_email_list('full').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group')
            set_admin_permissions(full: true, edit: true, view: true)
          elsif resource.admin_email_list('edit').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group'
            set_admin_permissions(full: false, edit: true, view: true)
          elsif resource.admin_email_list('view').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group'
            set_admin_permissions(full: false, edit: false, view: true)
          end
        else
          set_admin_permissions(full: false, edit: false, view: false)
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_to school_missing_path
    end
  end

  private

  def set_admin_permissions(full:, edit:, view:)
    @admin_full = full
    @admin_edit = edit
    @admin_view = view
  end
```

Comment: I think this question would be better received on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks...Didn't know about code review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you may want to look at using [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to properly encapsulate your permissions. This is a more formal way of defining access restrictions and testing for them in your controller and view code.

That being said, you can boil down your code considerably if you structure your code a little differently:

```
def admin_permissions
  return [ ] unless resource.present?

  case resource.ed_level
  when 'group'
    if current_user && (current_user.admin || resource.admins_byemail.include?(current_user.email))
      [ :full, :edit, :view ]
    else
      [ ]
    end
  else
    email = current_user && current_user.email.downcase

    if current_user && (current_user.admin || resource.admin_email_list('view').include?(email))
      if current_user.admin || resource.admin_email_list('full').include?(email)
        [ :full, :edit, :view ]
      elsif resource.admin_email_list('edit').include?(email)
        [ :edit, :view ]
      elsif resource.admin_email_list('view').include?(email)
        [ :view]
      end
    else
      [ ]
    end
  end
end
```

Then use this like so:

```
@admin_privs = admin_permissions
```

Define some helper methods like this:

```
def admin_full?
  @admin_privs and admin_privs.include?(:full)
end

def admin_edit?
  @admin_privs and admin_privs.include?(:edit)
end

def admin_view?
  @admin_privs and admin_privs.include?(:view)
end
```

Personally I've found that reducing duplication in your code by applying the "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY) principle often exposes the underlying structure and makes it easier to reshape it into something more concise and flexible.

For example, there were a number of tests here for `resource.ed_level != 'group'` when by virtue of being in the `else` block of a test asserting the opposite there was no way that would ever not be the case.

Comment: Thank you for such a clean and minimal solution. This will help clean up all of the instance variables in the views as well.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of Maxim's idea, but noticing that your permissions are hierarchical (i.e. "full" implies edit & view and "edit" implies view), I would condense your helper method to this:

```
def set_access_level(level)
  case level
  when :full
    @admin_full, @admin_edit, @admin_view = true, true, true
  when :edit
    @admin_full, @admin_edit, @admin_view = false, true, true
  when :view
    @admin_full, @admin_edit, @admin_view = false, false, true
  else
    @admin_full, @admin_edit, @admin_view = false, false, false
  end
end
```

And then your code becomes:

```
def admin_view
  if resource.present?
    if resource.ed_level == 'group'
      if current_user && (current_user.admin || resource.admins_byemail.include?(current_user.email))
        set_access_level(:full)
      else
        set_access_level(:none)
      end
    else
      if current_user && (current_user.admin || resource.admin_email_list('view').include?(current_user.email.downcase))
        if current_user.admin || (resource.admin_email_list('full').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group')
          set_access_level(:full)
        elsif resource.admin_email_list('edit').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group'
          set_access_level(:edit)
        elsif resource.admin_email_list('view').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group'
          set_access_level(:view)
        end
      else
        set_access_level(:none)
      end
    end
  else
    redirect_to school_missing_path
  end
end
```

Comment: I also want to point out that your ` && resource.ed_level != 'group'` assertions in the second part of your conditional are redundant; the fact you're not in the first branch of the top-level if-statement means you can assume that to be true.

Comment: Yeah this is a code base I've inherited...so I'm going through and refactoring to clean things up. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a setter helper method, like so:

```
def admin_view
  if resource.present?
    if resource.ed_level == 'group'
      if current_user && (current_user.admin || resource.admins_byemail.include?(current_user.email))
        set_values(true, true, true)
      else
        set_values(false, false, false)
      end
    else
      if current_user && (current_user.admin || resource.admin_email_list('view').include?(current_user.email.downcase))
        if current_user.admin || (resource.admin_email_list('full').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group')
          set_values(true, true, true)
        elsif resource.admin_email_list('edit').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group'
          set_values(false, true, true)
        elsif resource.admin_email_list('view').include?(current_user.email.downcase) && resource.ed_level != 'group'
          set_values(false, false, true)
        end
      else
        set_values(false, false, false)
      end
    end
  else
    redirect_to school_missing_path
  end
end

def set_values(full, edit, view)
  @admin_full = full
  @admin_edit = edit
  @admin_view = view
end
```

Comment: Nice...I like that option.

Comment: I've updated my code with the changes above...and used named arguments so it's more clean what is being set in the setter method.

Answer (score 0):

If find all nested ifs and repeated logic a bit confusing. Remember you can use the return statement to make the code more clean. I cannot guarantee the logic below is exactly what you are after but the structure is, in my opinion, more readable.

```
def admin_view
   redirect_to school_missing_path unless resource.present?
   access_level = calc_access_level

end

def calc_access_level

    return :none unless resource.present?
    return :none unless current_user
    return :full if current_user.admin

    email_raw = current_user.email
    email = email_raw.downcase

    if (resource.ed_level == 'group')
      return resource.admins_byemail.include?(email_raw) ? :full, :none
    end

    ['view','full','edit'].each do |access_level|
      if resource.admin_email_list(access_level).include?(email)
        return access_level.to_sym
      end
    end

    return :none

end

def set_access_level(level)

  @admin_full, @admin_edit, @admin_view = false, false, false
  case level
  when :full
    @admin_full, @admin_edit, @admin_view = true, true, true
  when :edit
    @admin_edit, @admin_view = true, true
  when :view
    @admin_view = true
  end
end
```